# obj-c looping over a string/string array in reverse

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string

I have a large string that has line breaks throughout.

```
NSString *exampleString = @"Many Lines \
                            Continue down \ 
                            Every line correctly has a character return at the end";
```

It is basically a log file, I am only interested in the latest few entries that are constantly being updated.

I am wondering if there is string functionality to do this and include a regex or an exact phrase to go through the string line by line in reverse, or am I better off turning the string into an array, then looping over the array line by line in reverse to search and process matches?

Comment: Are you actually reading from a file, or do you have the string in memory already? If you have a handle to the file, and it gets updated by another process or handle, your handle's location in the file won't change. You can just read from where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a skeletal structure:

```
NSArray* substringsArray = [exampleString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

[substringsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    if (idx < 5) {

        // first 5 objects

        NSString* substring = (NSString*)obj;

        // Do whatever
    }
}];
```

`NSArray* substringsArray = [exampleString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]` will break down your single string into an array of substrings, based on newline characters.
`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` will enumerate over the substrings in the array such that, `obj` here will be the substring. `idx` will tell you what index this string is at in the array.